# unable to get select to link push to the next page after pulling from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select, submit

I'm trying to set up a script to track reports for multiple teams and to quickly identify areas of improvement. 
MySQL and PHP are still very new to me, I have tried looking this up but I cannot seem to find what im looking for.

I have tried doing just a list, which does seem to work no problem when using just the a href and pulling the id. when trying to set it into a drop down list to make it cleaner the link breaks and will no loner push the queried info to the next page.

```
<?php
$sql = "select id, userID, lname, fname from agents order by lname ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<div class='userlist'>";
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){  echo "<option><a 
href='reports2.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['userID']."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I am expecting the drop down list to grow as users are added to the table, and to be able to push the queried info to the next page so when the form has been filled out and submitted, it will have the id(unique) username, first and last name, and time stamp for the report.

Comment: You can't mash `<a href=>` within an `<option>` field. It's either links **or** dropdown fields. You need `<select name=id>` and `<option value=123>` for the values to transpire with the form request. // Else showcase the generated output, and add more details on what you wanted to accomplish and what really happens.

Comment: I've tried using value as well where it defined prt of its value from the database table.

Comment: What I'm trying to get it to do is grab all the info for that line from the database and use it as part of the form to be pushed to the next table. There are 4 columns for the first db, user, fname ,lname, and leader. Those are pretty submitted and have both unique ID's and usernames. After it grabs that info bassed on who you select you fill out the rest of the form and when submit pushed the pulled info and the newly entered info to table 2

Comment: This would make it so a can search bassed on username from table 2 and see how many reports there, when they were entered and if there are two useres with similar names, makes sure they stay separate when grabbing the results.

Comment: @mengle You have not provided adequate information to help understand what you are having issues with. Showing the form being submitted is a start. Showing what report2.php contains is a step further.

If you just want the the user to be redirected to a link when they select an option the add a change event listener to the select element using javascript
`onchange='window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute(\"data-href\");'`. 
Each option whould now look like this;  
`echo "<option data-href=\"reports2.php?id=".$row['id']."\">".$row['userID']."</option>";`

Comment: sorry about not adding enough detail, the form functionality I was able to get to work without much work, and I had a basic list of uses on the first page that was all of like 300 users, this was why I was trying to do the drop down.

Comment: thank you so much for the js, I didnt even thing of that being needed. it works wonderfully after realizing where it needed to be inserted into.